# Give the api's response back to the client in batches with pagination using flask/python?

Tags: api, flask-restful

I am trying to figure out that if there is something that can help the use case mentioned below:

1. My use case is that I have an API that gives the response for the DB for a given time period. Now for the smaller time period, there is no issue but if the time period for which the query is being made increases then it will add a significant amount of time until the API responds. I do not want the UI to keep loading until the full response is received.

Thus I was thinking that there should be some mechanism using which I can get the response from the API in an incremental fashion(in batch) so that I can show the user and the user do not have to wait until the API is executed completely.

Any help on coding or design would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did some R/D and was able to fulfill my requirement with the **Pagination** package of **flask_mongoengine**

http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/

this has the sample implementations.